# getting the last inserted id from previous insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having a stored procedure with two insert statement, where I want to insert the ID of the first insert statement into the second one.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Log_Action] 
    @action_description VARCHAR(MAX),
    @creator_id INT,
    @entity VARCHAR(50),
    @entity_identifier UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value BIT;

    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO Action_Lookup (action_description)
        VALUES (@action_description);

        INSERT INTO Audit ([user_id], action_id, CREATED, [guid], entity, entity_identifier)
        VALUES (@creator_id, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), GETDATE(), NEWID(), @entity, @entity_identifier);

        SET @return_value = 1;
        RETURN @return_value;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        SET @return_value = 0;
        RETURN @return_value;

    END CATCH
END
```

the problem that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns null, I also tried  `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT` but non works.

Comment: Are you sure your ID column in table Action_Lookup is declared as identity?

Comment: @Ricardo yes it's identity.

Comment: Did you tried to put identity value into variable right after `insert into Action_Lookup` and then use value of this variable? Or do you have any triggers on `Action_Lookup` table?

Comment: This logic appears to work in SQL Fiddle (for a simplified example) . . . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41e6e/1.

Comment: is your first insert query "Action_Lookup" inserts any record ? it might happen there might be an error in the statement so there will not be any record inserted hence all three are not working

Answer (score 1):

Try `output` clause:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Log_Action]
    @action_description VARCHAR(MAX),
    @creator_id INT,
    @entity varchar(50),
    @entity_identifier uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value bit;

    BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO Action_Lookup (action_description)
    OUTPUT
        @creator_id,
        inserted.[id], -- in [] there should be actual name of identity column
        GETDATE(),
        NEWID(),
        @entity,
        @entity_identifier
        INTO Audit ([user_id], action_id, created, [guid], entity, entity_identifier) 
    VALUES (@action_description);

        set @return_value = 1;
        return @return_value;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        set @return_value = 0;
        return @return_value;
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I tried it and I got this error "The target table 'Audit' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK__Audit__action_id__19DFD96B'" which is true, action_id in table Audit references id in table Action_Lookup